# Adding custom routes on google map apps kml layer or alternatives

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kml

I'm working on Android google maps, I want to add a custom route between 2 places, I started drawing it on google maps I export it as Kml, when I try to add it as a layer to the map :

```
layer = new KmlLayer(mapAPI,R.raw.kml_samples, getApplicationContext()); // creating the kml layer
layer.addLayerToMap()
```

the debugger returns mapAPI:null  , 
as a result, I get my map without the layer created, 
can you help me with this? or recommend another way to do it! Thank you 
Android, Google-maps, Java, KmlLayer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `mapAPI` is referencing to a null object. Make sure that `mapAPI` is your `GoogleMap` object where the layer will be rendered as this is one of the things you need to render a KMLlayer from a local resource file. You may refer to the [Maps SDK for Android KML Importing Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml#add) for more information.

For an example of importing a KML file and creating a layer with it, take a look at the `KmlDemoActivity` in the demo app that ships with the utility library. To run the demo app, check the setup guide documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup).

I hope this helps!